# Array must be initalized with brace enclosed initalizer

Tags: c++

I am getting an error in the following function at the line where I initialize `e1` saying:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
   EmployeeInfo e1={id, n, p};
```

```
void addNewEmployee(){
  int id; char n[25]; double p;
  cout<<"\nEnter employee ID: "; cin>>id;
  cout<<"Enter employee name: "; cin>>n;
  cout<<"Enter employee pay rate: "; cin>>p;
  EmployeeInfo e1={id, n, p};
  ofstream fout("employee.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
  fout<<e1.employee_ID<<" "<<e1.name<<" "<<e1.pay_rate<<"\n";
}
```

struct employee info is given by:

```
struct EmployeeInfo
{
  int employee_ID;
  char name[25];
  double pay_rate;
};
```

How do I rectify this error?

Comment: They doing it like e1.employee_ID = id; and so on. Also why wouldn't use std::string instead of char arrays?

Comment: You can't assign (or initialise) one C-style array to another, which is what you're trying to do here.  Like william says, use `std::string`.

Comment: If you insist on using C-Style instead C++ Style `std::string`, use `strncpy(e1.name, n, 25);` to copy the string from `n` variable to  `EmployeeInfo::name` member.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I rectify this error?

Option 1:

Use `std::string` instead of `char[25]` for `name`.

```
struct EmployeeInfo
{
  int employee_ID;
  std::string name;
  double pay_rate;
};
```

### Option 2

Read directly into an object of `EmployeeInfo`.

```
void addNewEmployee(){
  EmployeeInfo e1;
  cout << "\nEnter employee ID: "; cin >> e1.employee_ID;
  cout << "Enter employee name: "; cin >> e1.name;
  cout << "Enter employee pay rate: "; cin >> e1.pay_rate;
  ofstream fout("employee.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
  fout << e1.employee_ID << " " << e1.name << " " << e1.pay_rate << "\n";
}
```

### Option 3

Use Option 1 *and* Option 2

```
struct EmployeeInfo
{
  int employee_ID;
  std::string name;
  double pay_rate;
};

void addNewEmployee(){
  EmployeeInfo e1;
  cout << "\nEnter employee ID: "; cin >> e1.employee_ID;
  cout << "Enter employee name: "; cin >> e1.name;
  cout << "Enter employee pay rate: "; cin >> e1.pay_rate;
  ofstream fout("employee.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
  fout << e1.employee_ID << " " << e1.name << " " << e1.pay_rate << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
EmployeeInfo e1={id, n, p};
```

tries to initialize the array `EmployeeInfo::name` with the array `n`.

That's not possible.

You should use a `std::string`. If you have to use a C string/array you can't inizialize the object. You have to set the elements, e.g. with:

```
struct EmployeeInfo {
  int employee_ID;
  char name[25];
  double pay_rate;
};

void addNewEmployee() {
  int id; char n[25]; double p;
  cout<<"\nEnter employee ID: "; cin>>id;
  cout<<"Enter employee name: "; cin>>n;
  cout<<"Enter employee pay rate: "; cin>>p;
  EmployeeInfo e1;
  e1.employee_ID = id;
  std::memcpy(e1.name, n, 25);
  e1.pay_rate = p;
  ofstream fout("employee.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
  fout<<e1.employee_ID<<" "<<e1.name<<" "<<e1.pay_rate<<"\n";
}
```

You also could use a constructor:

```
struct EmployeeInfo {
  EmployeeInfo(int id, char *n, double p) : employee_ID(id), pay_rate(p) { std::memcpy(name, n, 25); }
  int employee_ID;
  char name[25];
  double pay_rate;
};

void addNewEmployee() {
  int id; char n[25]; double p;
  cout<<"\nEnter employee ID: "; cin>>id;
  cout<<"Enter employee name: "; cin>>n;
  cout<<"Enter employee pay rate: "; cin>>p;
  EmployeeInfo e1 {id, n, p};
  ofstream fout("employee.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
  fout<<e1.employee_ID<<" "<<e1.name<<" "<<e1.pay_rate<<"\n";
}
```

But you really should prefer `std::string`.